# C# Linq Reading File into List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv

Im reading csv files into a list. since each file contains many lines and time-consuming to read, I only need to check the first 100 lines for each file. How can I have Linq to only read first 100 lines and then continue to the next file?

```
For(i=0;i<10;i++)
     line_list = (from line in File.ReadLines(files[i])
                  let field = line.Split(',')
                  where field[2] == "Apple" && !field[3].Contains("Banana")
                  select field).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Take` to take only the first 100 lines:

```
var first100Lines = File.ReadLines(path).Take(100);
```

for what it's worth, here the all in one:

```
List<List<string[]>> allFileLineColumns = files
    .Select(fPath => 
        File.ReadLines(fPath)
            .Take(100)
            .Select(l => new { Line=l, Cols=l.Split(',') })
            .Where(x => x.Cols.Length >= 4 && x.Cols[2] == "Apple" && !x.Cols[3].Contains("Banana"))
            .Select(x => x.Cols)
            .ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

Although i would split it into multiple parts to increase readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird use case for linq, but try take()...

```
For(i=0;i<10;i++)
     line_list = (from line in File.ReadLines(files[i]).Take(100)
                  let field = line.Split(',')
                  where field[2] == "Apple" && !field[3].Contains("Banana")
                  select field).ToList();
```

Comment: The `Take` should be on `ReadLines` as in Tims example. Otherwise it processes all the lines anyway and then `Take`s 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concat the result into  line_list

```
          for(i=0; i<10; i++)
          {
              var fieldsList = from line in File.ReadLines(files[i])
                               let field = line.Split(',')
                               where field[2] == "Apple" && !field[3].Contains("Banana")
                               select field;

                line_list = line_list.Concat(fieldsList.Take(100).ToList()).ToList();
          }
```